# Pandas: Cumulative Sum From Start to End

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with start and end positions. I want to squash rows, where `end_n` is close to `start_n+1` and add the corresponding values. In the end I want the cumulative sum and the start and end values from which that sum came.

Example indata, allowing a distance of <5 from `end_n` to `start_n+1`:

```
           start        end       value
1          0            10        3
2          11           15        4
3          17           20        5
4          45           50        3
5          51           60        13
6          100          120       9
```

Desired result:

```
           start        end       value
1          0            10        3
2          11           15        4
3          17           20        5
4          45           50        3
5          51           60        13
6          100          120       9
```

or

```
           start        end       sum
1          0            20        12
4          45           60        16
6          100          120       9
```

I suppose a lambda function would do it, but the original data is large and that would impact performance. I would prefer a pure pandas/numpy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract shifted values and comapre if greater like `5` with cumulative sums for groups and then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
g = df['start'].sub(df['end'].shift(fill_value=0)).gt(5).cumsum()

df = df.groupby(g).agg(start=('start', 'first'), end=('end','last'), sum=('value','sum'))
print (df)
   start  end  sum
0      0   20   12
1     45   60   16
2    100  120    9
```